# Civimail - How to manage Headers, Footers, ... in Message Templates?

Tags: civimail

My CiviCRM manages several organisations, each having their own Header, Footer, ...

I would like to create at least one Message Template for each of them, each Template having its own Header, Footer, ...

How can I do that ?
If I can't, what is the use of Headers, Footers, ... ; how can I choose between different ones ?

Comment: Why not build the info that you want in the Header/Footer directly in to each organisations Template?

Comment: Thank you Pete ; Yes, of course, but I thought that it it would have made sense  to include Headers, Footers, ... in a template.

Comment: Given your comment below about keeping it as simple as possible, the imo having to pick only the template, rather than the template and the footer and the header, would be simpler

Answer (score 1):

The header and footers are used for civimail, the usual way is to have templates that don't contain any header or footer but choose them when you compose the email

Another option you might consider is the new [mosaico extension](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico), that should make it easier to style your mailings

Comment: I want something as simple as possible for my Organisations Administrators : these would be too complex.

Comment: choosing a header isn't more complex than choosing a template?